# Sorting with two criterion

Tags: c

I am writing a code and in the middle of it,I have to sort some data.
For example we have a struct named fruits like this:

```
struct fruits{
int price;
int quality;
};
```

(0<=quality<=10 and the price can be any positive integer)

We get an array of fruits from the user and we get each fruits' price and quality.

Then I want to print the fruits's information in an order that the cheaper fruits with be printed first and if the price was the same the information of the fruit that has better quality have to be printed first.

for example :
input:
4 0

4 5

3 2

6 8

6 4

(the first is the price the second is the quality)

output:

3 2

4 5

4 0

6 8

6 4

I need help in the sorting part because I have no idea how can we sort with two criterion

Comment: And how do you sort with *one* criterion?! Presumably you've written code for it already? If that's the case, then the *"cheaper fruits with be printed first and if the price was the same the information of the fruit that has better quality have to be printed first"* is pretty straightforward step from *"cheaper fruits with be printed first"*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala no,I mean if two fruit have the same price,then the fruit that has the higher quality must be printed first

Comment: :@bj - apart from the amusing name - have you got some code for sorting with one attribute. If so, just alter the comparison operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int price;
    int quality;
} fruit;



int cmpfruits(const void* p1, const void* p2) {
    const fruit* f1=p1;
    const fruit* f2=p2;
    if ( f1->price <  f2->price ) return -1;
    if ( f1->price == f2->price ) {
        if ( f1->quality <  f2->quality ) return 1;
        if ( f1->quality >  f2->quality ) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    fruit f[] = {{1,2},{1,1},{1,3},{2,0},{-1,100}};
    qsort(&f,sizeof(f)/sizeof(fruit),sizeof(fruit),cmpfruits);
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%i/%i\n", f[i].price, f[i].quality);
    }
}
```

Comment: oops, was a case my test didn't cover but it should work as intended now

Answer (score -1):

You should use the standard `qsort` function. You will have to write a comparison function that suites your needs. Here first try to make a choice on price and if they are the same, make the difference on quality.

```
int fruit_cmp(void *a, void *b)
{
    struct fruits *fa = a, *fb = b;
    if (fa->price < fb->price)
        return 1;
    if (fa->price > fb->price)
        return -1;
    if (fa->quality < fb->quality)
        return -1;
    if (fa->quality > fb->quality)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `qsort` is C++?

Comment: Perhaps `fa.price>fb.price ? 1 : 1`

Comment: @Osiris you mean prices can be negative? From a reality perspective I do not think they can overflow. But I get your point and will edit accordingly.